# Why doesn't this ASP.NET Core code work on remote host

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an Angular web site that works on my local host. When I upload it to a remote host, it fails without an error. Just doesn't save any files.

I have searched the web for an answer. No joy.

This never returns an error on either the local Visual Studio 2019 or the remote.

Found the basic code on Microsoft site. Looked at a lot of angular sites

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UploadController : ControllerBase
{
    private IHostingEnvironment env;

    public UploadController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        env = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    [HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
    {
        try
        {
            var files = Request.Form.Files;

            if (files.Count < 1)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            if (files.Any(f => f.Length == 0))
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                string folderName = $"Project_{file.FileName}";
                string webRootPath = env.WebRootPath;
                string newPath = Path.Combine(Startup.documentPath, folderName);
                if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
                }

                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).Name.Trim('"');
                    string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, fileName);

                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
                    }

                    using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                         await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Ok("All the files are successfully uploaded.".csConverToJSON());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you sending the files? My guess is that `Request.Form.Files` is an empty list (not `null`, but just has no entries). In that case, it would just skip the whole `foreach` loop and declare success. You can confirm this by setting a breakpoint in your `Update()` code.

Comment: Is the api controller failing or is the angular site failing? You should try and hit the api endpoint using postman and see if it returns an error.

Comment: @GabrielLuci If `Request.Form.Files` was empty, it would `return BadRequest();` (first `if` block).

Comment: Check your Network tab after attempting to upload a file using your Angular form -- you may be seeing errors. Perhaps 500 errors? If so, it means the identity your process is running under may not have permission to your file system to create the folder and files.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yeah I guess it would :) Missed that.

Comment: Do you get any error in network tab? Try to enable asp.net core stdout log to check whether there is any error in server side. In addition, try to add log feature to every line to check which line stop your function.

Comment: This is the answer. When uploaded to remote server, the client tried to send the files to the wron server. Thanks to everyone for your help